# Disable "Print..." in Context menu of selected text in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, printing, context-menu, user-interface

When I select some text on page, displayed in the Chrome web-browser, and click with my right button, context menu opens. It has three options: "Copy", "Search %YOUR.SEARCH.ENGINE.NAME for '%SELECTED.TEXT%" and "Print..."; then is has separator and "Inspect Element".

My usual usage of popup menu on selected text is to use "Search %% for '%%'", but sometimes I miss the right menu item and clicks on "Print...". Then print preview opens (or OS print dialog if `--disable-print-preview` command-line option was added. I have no printer, and I need not to print one or two words, I just want

Is it possible to disable "Print..." item in the Google's version of Chrome?

If it is not possible, how can I find the code to display "Print..." in Chromium?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Printing can be disabled completely by setting:

```
"printing": {
   "enabled": false
},
```

to the `Preferences` file. Internally this sets [kPrintingEnabled](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#search/&q=kPrintingEnabled&sq=package:chromium&type=cs).

Comment: So, it is possible to do binary patch of compiled `render_view_context_menu.cc`'s function `RenderViewContextMenu::AppendPluginItems` / `AppendPageItems` / `AppendPrintItem`? I think the needed code path is only in `AppendPrintItem`

Comment: There is `profile_->GetPrefs()->GetBoolean(prefs::kPrintingEnabled)` code in `AppendPrintItem`. Is it possible to globally set `kPrintingEnabled` flag to false? How?

Comment: This way: Open the profile folder, find the JSON file `Preferences`, find "printing" field (browser->extensions->printing), then add `,
"enabled": false` into it. Dan D, Thank you for digging into the code,  the keys was found via [query on codesearch.debian.net "kPrintingEnabled"](http://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=kPrintingEnabled) in `src/chrome/common/pref_names.cc` (`Boolean controlling whether printing is enabled. const char kPrintingEnabled[] = "printing.enabled";`), after checking the `RenderViewContextMenu::AppendPrintItem` function. Please update your answer with JSON edit method.

Comment: Ok, I cleaned up the question to the solution. The rest if need is in the revision history.

Comment: Yes, it is in the top section, my comment about "browser->extensions" was wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I always kept clicking it accidentally. You can find this file in: %AppData% then go to ..\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences on Windows

Comment: This doesn't work. Chrome restore the `Preferences` file after I saved it.

Comment: @zwcloud Did you exit Chrome completely before changing the file?

Comment: @DanD. Thanks! Just tried again and it works. Yes, Chrome should be closed before editing `Preferences`.

Comment: This removes 'Print...' from the context menu, but also disables printing altogether (as of 84.0.4147.135), be sure this is what you want before applying.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me as of 2021. I had to use the local Group Policy Editor (GPO).

1. Download the [Google Chrome Enterprise](https://chromeenterprise.google/browser/download/) installer zip file
2. Find a file called `chrome.adm` in it under (`Configuration\adm\en-US`)
3. Add it to Administrative Templates in GP editor
4. Through there, disable printing (Administrative Templates > Classic Administrative Templates(ADM) > Google > Google Chrome > Printing) .

Comment: Any idea what the equivalent is on Ubuntu Linux?